# Scala - How to avoid java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when Row.get(i) would retrieve a null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I'm using Spark and Scala to read some parquet files. The problem I am facing is the content of this parquet files may vary, that is some fields sometimes are not present. So when I try to access a fields which doesn't exist in a file, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "wrongHeaderIndicator" does
>   not exist.

I did something similar in Java once, and it was possible to use `contains()` or `get(index)!= null` to check if the field we are trying to access exists or not. But I am not able to do the same in Scala.

Below you can see what I have written so far and the four things I tried, without success.

```
//The part of reading the parquet file and accessing the rows works fine
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val parquetFileDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("myParquet.parquet')

//I get one of the six blocks in the parquet file
val myHeaderData = parquetFileDF.select("HeaderData").collectAsList()

//When I try to access a particular field which is not in the "HeaderData"
//I get the exception

//1st Try
Option(myHeaderData.get(0).getStruct(0).getAs[String]("wrongHeaderIndicator")) match {
      case Some(i) => println("This data exist")
      case None => println("This would be a null") 
}

//2nd Try
if(myHeaderData.get(0).getStruct(0).getAs[String]("wrongHeaderIndicator")!= null)
        println("This data exist")
    else
        println("This is null")

//3rd Try
println(myHeaderData.get(0).getStruct(0).fieldIndex("wrongHeaderIndicator"))

//4th Try
println(Some(myHeaderData.get(0).getStruct(0).getAs[String]("wrongHeaderIndicator")))
```

Edit. **The problem is not when I access the columns of the DataFrame**. The columns are always the same, and I don't need to perform checkings before the select. The problem come once I access the fields of the records in a particular column. Those records are structures which schema you can see below:

The schema of the column myHeaderData is similar to:

```
|-- myHeaderData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- myOpIndicator: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mySecondaryFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- myDownloadDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- myDownloadTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- myUUID: string (nullable = true)
```

And if I run

```
myHeaderData.get(0).getStruct(0).schema
```

I get the following output:

> StructType(StructField(myOpIndicator,StringType,true),
>   StructField(mySecondaryFlag,StringType,true),
>   StructField(myDownloadDate,StringType,true),
>   StructField(myDownloadTime,StringType,true),
>   StructField(myUUID,StringType,true))

The four things I tried produce the same exception. Can anyone tell me what can I use to check if a field exist in a structure without generating the Exception?

Thanks

Comment: I want to mention I did look for this question already in stackoverflow, but I couldn't find a solution for my problem. If someones could refer me to an already answered question, please add it in this comment and I will close this question on my own.

Comment: It seems That you are trying to look up "wrongHeaderIndicator" and compare its output. But you should be cheking if "wrongHeaderIndicator" itself exists.

Comment: @Gabain1993 Yes. How can I check it if exist

Comment: @user8371915, no. I do know how to detect if there is a column in a data grame. Here what I want is to check if there is an element inside a structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making wrong assumption. If `getAs` field which doesn't exist it will throw exception, not return `null`. Therefore you should use `Try`:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val row: Row = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq(
  """{"myHeaderData": {"myOpIndicator": "foo"}}"""))).first

Try(row.getAs[Row]("myHeaderData").getAs[String]("myOpIndicator")) match {
  case Success(s) => println(s)
  case _ => println("error")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The Try { } instead of the Option{ } made the trick and there is not exception anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check if a column exists in your dataframe or not. Use the `df.columns` method to get an array with all the headers in your data, then check if your column (`wrongHeaderIndicator`) is in the array or not. Here is a short example:

```
val df = Seq(("aaa", "123"), ("bbb", "456"), ("ccc", "789")).toDF("col1", "col2")
df.show()

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
| aaa| 123|
| bbb| 456|
| ccc| 789|
+----+----+
```

Using `df.columns.toList` will now give you `List(col1, col2)`. To check if your field is present or not, simply do `df.columns.contains("fieldName")`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but that part is aready solved in the code I posted, myHeaderData is already a column. The problem is with the next step. Each column has several records and each record is a structure, which may contain from 1 to 5 fields. Sometimes all of the 5 fields are present, sometimes not. And there is well I'm having the problems

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre Ah, I see. I must have misunderstood you. Can you post some example of how the structure looks like?